# {assertr::assert} on subset of dataframe within pipe

Tags: r, assertion

I would like to {assertr} `assert` on a subset of a dataframe. I have a workaround with `verify` but get an error with `assert` when piping. Is there a way to `assert` on a subset of a dataframe via piping? See reprex below. Thank you for your help!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(assertr)

# For cars with 6 cyl, vs is NOT na
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6) %>% 
  count(!is.na(vs))
#>   !is.na(vs) n
#> 1       TRUE 7

# Success: Verify that no rows with cyl 6 and vs na
mtcars %>% 
  assertr::verify(nrow(filter(., cyl == 6 & is.na(vs))) == 0) %>% 
  head()
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# Success: Assert without piping
assertr::assert(filter(mtcars, cyl == 6), not_na, vs)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

# Error: Assert that vs NOT na when cyl 6
mtcars %>% 
  assertr::assert(filter(., cyl == 6), not_na, vs)
#> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `not_na` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

EDIT: I made a mistake above - asserting without piping doesn't meet my needs since the output is filtered...

```
# Assert without piping runs but the output is filtered
assertr::assert(filter(mtcars, cyl == 6), not_na, vs)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

Comment: Not tested but you probably need to wrap it in braces to inhibit the default behavior of placing the LHS of the pipe as the first argument on the RHS. `mtcars %>% { assertr::assert(filter(., cyl == 6), not_na, vs) }`.

Comment: Thanks, Ritchie. That runs! But the output is filtered, as is one of my "solutions" above by mistake. So doesn't meet my needs. I've edited the question to clarify.